# Where is electromagnetic induction in the Jefimenko equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

[image: Equations from Wikipedia]

I'm currently exploring the [Jefimenko Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) and practicing using them to find things like the electric field from a particle or the magnetic field around a current. In general, I've read that the Jefimenko Equations are an alternative to the Maxwell Equations. However, one thing that I can't seem to figure out is electromagnetic induction:

$$\nabla\times \boldsymbol{E} = -\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}$$

From this Maxwell Equation, we can figure out the voltage induced in a wire that has a changing magnetic field through it using Stokes' Theorem. However, the Jefimenko equation for $\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r},t)$ does not contain a term for a changing magnetic field. So how do the equations explain the induced voltage in a wire from a changing magnetic field using Jefimenko's Equations?

Comment: As a note, I suspect that L. V. Lorenz published "Jefimenko" equations already in about 1860.

Comment: If the magnetic field is changing, a current is changing to produce it, which is why the electric field has a $\partial \mathbf{J}/\partial t$ term.

Comment: @Javier, I believe that's the term for electromagnetic waves right? I thought induction was different than EM radiation? Also, how would it explain the induced voltage from a moving magnet?

Answer (score 4):

Ignatowski's equations follow from the representation of the fields by the vector and scalars as
$$\begin{align}\mathbf{E}&=-\nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t} \tag{1}\label{1}\\
\mathbf{B}&= \nabla \times\mathbf A  \tag{2}\label{2} \end{align}$$
These two represent Faraday's induction law.

When you substitute the integrals into $\eqref{1}$ and$\eqref{2}$
$$\begin{align} \mathbf A &= \frac{\mu_0}{ 4\pi}\int \frac{[\mathbf J]}{R}dV \tag{3}\label{3}\\
\phi &= \frac{1}{ 4\pi \epsilon_0 } \int\frac{[\rho]}{R}dV \tag{4}\label{4} \end{align}$$
you recover Ignatowski's equations.
For details see McDonald: "The Relation Between Expressions for Time-Dependent Electromagnetic Fields Given by Jefimenko and by Panofsky and Phillips", Am. J. Phys. 65 (11), November 1997

Comment: So I'm kind of a noob when it comes to electromagnetism and the mathematics behind it. As a result, I'm struggling to see how the derivation of the equations would give us a method of calculating the induced voltage in a wire using only the two equations. Could you explain to me where the term for induction would be in the Ignatowski's/Jefimenko's equations (if there is one)? Am I just misunderstanding what Ignatowski's equations are?

Comment: for any solenoidal vector field $\mathbf{v}$, that is if $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}=0$ can be written as $\mathbf{v} = \nabla \times \mathbf{a}$ for some $\mathbf{a}$; therefore $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = \nabla \times (\mathbf{E}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t}=0.$ That is the vector field $\mathbf{E}+\frac {\partial \mathbf{A} }{\partial t}$ is lamellar and can be written as the gradient of a scalar field: $\mathbf{E}+\frac {\partial \mathbf{A}} {\partial t} = -\nabla \phi$ ....

Comment: The scalar $\phi$ and vector potentials $\mathbf{A}$ are directly related to charge $\rho$ and current $\mathbf{J}$ densities, resp., see (3) and (4), and Ignatowski's equations are that relationship after differentiating the integrals with appropriate precautions taken for retardation in time.